# Optimize query with big-table-join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have one big table.

Let's call it 'unicorns'.

And second table 'farmers'.

Structure:

**farmers**

- id
- name
- ... some more fields

**unicorns**

- id
- farmer_id
- ... some more fields

And there is query:

```
SELECT
  f.id,
  f.name,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  farmers f 
LEFT JOIN unicorns u 
ON u.farmer_id = f.id 
GROUP BY f.id
```

Of course tables are really named not this way and have more fields etc. But I have left only the most important things in my example.

The problem is that the system grows, and there are too many unicorns. Millions.

And this query (like-this) is executed on farmers list page.

And page is loading not so fast as before, because we join a multi-million table each time we load page.

**Problem is:**

- We really need to display each farmer's unicorns count in the list.
- We need to improve page load speed.

If you would need to optimize this, how would you achieve this result?

What would you recommend?

*P.S.*

*Personally I think I need to exclude big-table-join from the main query, calculate unicorns counts separately and store them in the cache storage, recalculate them time after time. Maybe there is the best way, so I wanted to hear someone else's opinion.*

Comment: Are both `id` fields `PRIMARY KEY`s and do you have an index on `unicorns.farmer_id`?

Comment: Yes, I am aware about primary keys, foreign keys and indexes

Comment: Have you tried executing the query directly (using phpmyadmin, shell,  ...) to check execution time and make sure it's really this query slowing down page load?

Comment: Is calculating the unicorn count per farmer in the unicorn table alone (without joining the farmer table) considerably quicker than your current query?

Comment: Query as it is posted initially do not require `unicorns` relation at all. Please, post a proper query.

Comment: What's the output of `EXPLAIN <your query>` and how many farmers don't have unicorns?

Comment: 117465 unicorns and 3203 farmers currently in my tables (trimmed dev DB, mush more in prod). Big query = 0.14s. Small query(unicorns-table-only) = 0.013s.

Comment: So, perhaps it will be much slower if caculate per each farmer separately.

Comment: Around 1/3 farmers have no unicorns

Comment: did you think about making a summary table and updateing it periodically?

Comment: Thanks for downvoters. It is much easier to downvote then to read the question and give the qood answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just have an extra column on the farmer's table for NumberUnicorns and store it there.  Then, via some database triggers, when a record is added to the unicorn table, it just updates the farmers table with the respective count from the new record.  Also consider updating the count if unicorn records are deleted.  Then, your query is immediately from the farmers table -- done.

Comment: Thank you. After some thoughts and research I have decided that your method is best.